# Counting number ways of expressing a given integer as a sum of other integers

Tags: combinatorics

Consider this counting problems

```
 1. In  how  many  ways  can  a  given  positive  integer  n  ≥ 2  be 
   expressed  as  the  sum of 2 positive integers (which are not
   necessarily distinct). For example,  for  n  =  3,  the  number  of 
   ways  is  2,  i.e.,  1+2,  2+1. Give  only  the  answer  without any
   explanation.
 2. In  how  many  ways  can  a  given  positive integer n  ≥ 3  be 
   expressed  as  the  sum of 3 positive integers (which are not
   necessarily distinct). For example,  for  n  =  4, the  number  of 
   ways  is  3,  i.e.,  1+2+1,  2+1+1.  Give  only  the answer without
   any explanation.
 3. In  how  many  ways  can  a given  positive  integer n  ≥ k  be  
    expressed  as  the  sum of k positive integers (which are not   
    necessarily distinct)? Give only the answer without explanation.
```

I'm coming up with these ans

1.

> $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$

2.

> $n-3$

Becasue of this pattern
$$n=4\ (2+1+1)$$
$$n=5\ (3+1+1), (2+2+1)$$
$$n=6\ (4+1+1), (3+2+1), (2+2+2)$$
$$n=7\ (5+1+1), (4+2+1), (3+3+1), (3+2+2)$$

How can we generalize this i.e. How can we count in case of 3.

Comment: You may find [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) useful.

Comment: In question 1, 1+2 and 2+1 were counted as different sums. If this applies to the second question then 2+1+1, 1+2+1 and 1+1+2 would all be distinct sums.  Good luck!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29

Comment: Don't ask 3 questions in the same time, you will get only answers from people knowing all of them. Ask this in 3 different question, it is absolutely not a problem here (until the questions are independent).

Comment: @PeterHorvath All of them were related to each other that's why I Posted them togehter

Comment: @Atinesh Then you get good answers and upvotes with a much lower chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have spotted that your answer to the first question cannot be right: for $n=3$ it yields the value $\left\lfloor\frac32\right\rfloor=1$, while the problem clearly states that the answer is $2$. The example in the problem shows that different orders of the same summands are counted separately: $1+2$ and $2+1$ are counted as distinct decompositions. Your answer would be correct if the order of the summands didn’t matter. For the problem as given, however, you have $a+b=n$, where $a$ can be any of the positive integers $1,2,\ldots,n-1$, and $b$ is then uniquely determined as $n-a$. Thus, there are $n-1$ decompositions.

Your answer to the second question is incorrect for the same reason. For $n=3$ there is one way, $1+1+1$, not $0$. For $n=4$ there are $3$ ways, $2+1+1,1+2+1$, and $1+1+2$, not $1$; and so on. If you make a table for the first few values of $n\ge 3$, you get this:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&3&4&5&6&7\\
\text{Nr. of ways}:&1&3&6&10&15
\end{array}$$

You can easily get these numbers from the decompositions that you’ve listed in your question. And they follow a very clear pattern, from which you can derive a general expression involving a binomial coefficient.

If you notice that $n-1=\binom{n-1}1$, so that the answer to the first question is also a binomial coefficient, you might suspect that the answer to the general (third) question is also a binomial coefficient, and you might even be able to guess what it is, if you hypothesize that the lower number in the binomial coefficient follows a simple rule.

Alternatively, you could notice that you’re asking for the number of solutions in positive integers to the equation

$$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k=n$$

or, equivalently, the number of ways of distributing $n$ indistinguishable balls amongst $k$ boxes, subject to the requirement that each box receive at least one ball. There’s a standard elementary way to analyze this problem; it’s often called the *stars and bars* method, and it’s explained reasonably well [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29#Theorem_one).

Comment: I misunderstood the meaning of "Which are not
   necessarily distinct". You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$[x^n]\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^k = \binom{n-1}{k-1}.$$
See also [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).